# При досрочном завершении FSM, бот зависает

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

У меня есть тг-бот, который имеет несколько команд, две из них активируют машину состояний.
Моя проблема: я активирую FSM и прохожу последовательность вопросов, но решаю до конца не отвечать и ввожу боту совершенно другую команду. Реакция бота при этом следующая: он продолжает последовательность состояний в FSM, а затем и вовсе зависает. Как можно это исправить? Я много, где задавал этот вопрос, но никто так и не смог дать ответ, надеюсь на сообщество

Начало кода код:

```
class Protest(StatesGroup):
    full_name = State()
    team_name = State()
    enemy = State()
    date = State()
    time = State()
    cause = State()
```

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=["protest"], state=None)
async def start_protest(message: types.Message):
    await Protest.full_name.set()
    await message.answer("Введите Ваше ФИО:")


@dp.message_handler(state=Protest.full_name)
async def name_protest(message: types.Message, state=FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data["full_name"] = message.text
    await Protest.next()
    await message.answer("Введите название Вашей команды:")
```

Конец кода:

```
@dp.message_handler(state=Protest.cause)
async def cause_protest(message: types.Message, state=FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data["cause"] = message.text
    await protest_db.sql_add_command(state)
    await state.finish()
    await message.answer("Ваш протест будет рассмотрен")


def register_handlers_protest(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(start_protest, commands=["protest"], state=None)
    dp.register_message_handler(name_protest, state=Protest.full_name)
    dp.register_message_handler(teem_name_protest, state=Protest.team_name)
    dp.register_message_handler(enemy_teem, state=Protest.enemy)
    dp.register_message_handler(inline_kb_answer_callback_handler, state=Protest.date)
    dp.register_message_handler(time_match, state=Protest.time)
    dp.register_message_handler(cause_protest, state=Protest.cause)
```

Я нарочно не вставляю промежуточный код, так он очень длинный, что может помешать вам и однотипный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте такой хендлер для сброса состояния

```
@dp.message_handler(command=['cancel'], state="*")
async def cancel_fsm(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.finish()
```